# access nmcli from php

Tags: php, linux, bash, wifi

I want to use nmcli within a php script using the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)-function. Everything works well except that when calling

```
nmcli -m multiline -f all d wifi
```

from the command line, it will show me all conntections and calling it from php like this

```
exec("nmcli -m multiline -f all d wifi",$output,$result);
echo $output[0];
```

ends up in an empty string.

Do I need to add the www-data user to a certain usergroup that allows to list available connections?

**[UPDATE]**
After calling

```
sudo -u www-data bash -c "nmcli --nocheck -m multiline -f all d wifi list 2>&1"
```

I got the following error message

```
** (process:22156): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient
/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: Rejected send message, 3 matched rules; 
type="method_call", sender=":1.100" (uid=33 pid=22156 comm="nmcli --nocheck 
-m multiline -f all d wifi list ") 
interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="    
(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" 
(uid=0 pid=677 comm="NetworkManager ")
```

**[UPDATE]**
According to [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=143640) I updated the file /org/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf and allowed all for the default. Now it works with some Warnings. But like this

```
sudo -u www-data bash -c "nmcli --nocheck -m multiline -f all d wifi list 2>/dev/null"
```

it works as expected. But I still cannot connect to a network with this error comming up:

```
** (process:7969): Warning **: Could not create objct for
/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5: No session found for uid 33 (unknown)
```

Comment: Have you tried actually running the command as the www-data user? Or try it with exec("nmcli -m multiline -f all d wifi 2>&1",$output,$result); to see the actual error message.

Comment: giving (root) pivileges to www-data doesnt seem like a good idea to me. I dont know what the purpose of your script is , but I'd suggest using a cronjob (as root) (or network post-up script) to execute the nmcli command, and write it to a txt file. Than simply have your php script read the txt.

Comment: @lxer  there is no way arround it. I need it that way.

Comment: @Chris there are no errors that occur.

Comment: is selinux enabled on your machine?

Comment: @Chris no, I'm on a Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: selinux is a kernel-module, which enforces security on linux. I guess it's enabled on Ubuntu by default. It messes up a lot of things, if you don't know how to use it. Have you tried both: running the command directly as www-data user on command line and in PHP with redirecting error-output by appending "2>&1" to the command? If there is no error message whatsoever, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: @Chris thanks for that tip. I updated the question with the error output